# android spinner is trigger by magic

Tags: android, spinner

I have a Spinner in my application which is installed and configured as follow:

```
  final Spinner left = getLeftShiftSpinner();  //simple gets the Spinner by Id
  left.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            left.setSelection(0);
            try {
                Log.d("test", "SHIFT_LEFT");
                String s = content.shiftLeft(i);
                content.clear();
                updateScreen(s);
            } catch (ScreenContent.WrongSyntaxException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
        }
    });
```

When I compile everything and the app starts on my device I get the Output "SHIFT_LEFT" from the `Log.d(...)` but I DID NOT click on anything at all. The application simply started and then by doing nothing the `onItemSelectedListener` is triggered?? Does anyone know why??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the view is first inflated/activity loaded the spinner selects the first item in its list, triggering on the `onItemSelected` listener.

EDIT: example using boolean variable to ignore first trigger

```
    boolean isInitTrigger = true;
    final Spinner left = getLeftShiftSpinner(); // simple gets the Spinner by Id
    left.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            if(isInitTrigger){
                isInitTrigger = false;
                return;
            }

            left.setSelection(0);
            try {
                Log.d("test", "SHIFT_LEFT");
                String s = content.shiftLeft(i);
                content.clear();
                updateScreen(s);
            } catch (ScreenContent.WrongSyntaxException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can I supress this auto `onitemselected`-trigger or filter it somehow?

Comment: you can handle it manually one way or another. one option would be to set a boolean variable to essentially ignore the first trigger of the listener, then reset that variable `onResume()`.

Comment: added example above, just don't forget to set `isInitTrigger` to true again in `onResume()`